# Well-ordering $\mathbb R$ in ZF + "$2^{\aleph_0} \nrightarrow (\aleph_1, \aleph_1)^2$".

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ramsey-theory

It is well-known that $2^{\aleph_0} \nrightarrow (\aleph_1, \aleph_1)^2$. The usual proof uses a well-ordering of $\mathbb R$ to find a colouring depending on the difference between the usual order and well-order of $\mathbb R$, and so it uses the axiom of choice.

My question is: Can we use the statement $2^{\aleph_0} \nrightarrow (\aleph_1, \aleph_1)^2$ to well-order $\mathbb R$ in ZF? If not, then what choice principles can we prove in ZF + "$2^{\aleph_0} \nrightarrow (\aleph_1, \aleph_1)^2$"? Thank you.

Comment: I'd imagine the statement holds in the Cohen model.

Comment: @AsafKaragila so, what can we say?

Comment: Probably not a whole lot. Although truth be told, I don't even remember the definition of $\kappa\to(\alpha,\beta)^2$.

Comment: $2^{\aleph_0}\not\to(\aleph_1,\aleph_1)^2$ holds in any model of "all sets are Lebesgue measurable" (like Solovay's model or models of the axiom of determinacy), simply because in such a model the continuum has no subset of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass What if $2^{\aleph_0}\not\to(\aleph_1,\aleph_1)^2$ is strengthened to $2^{\aleph_0}\not\to(\text{uncountable, uncountable})^2$?

Comment: @AndreasBlass, bof: Which one is $\kappa\to(\alpha,\beta)^2$ anyway?

Comment: I didn’t understand anything from this conversation.