# Proving Sierpinski’s result without choice.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ramsey-theory

Recently, I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4295968/814070) about whether we can well-order $\mathbb R$ over $\sf ZF$ using Sierpinski’s result ($2^{\aleph_0} \nrightarrow (\aleph_1, \aleph_1)^2)$.

As pointed out in the comments, the statement holds trivially, for example, in Solovay’s model since there are no subsets of $\mathbb R$ with cardinality $\aleph_1$ in Solovay’s model. Since $\mathbb R$ can’t be well-ordered in Solovay’s model, the result does not imply the fact that $\mathbb R$ can be well-ordered.

Also, if $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of (WLOG disjoint) sets, say, $\mathbb R = \bigsqcup_{i \in \mathbb N} A_i$, where each $A_i$ is countable, then we can colour $\{x,y\}$ blue if $x$ and $y$ belong to the same $A_i$, red otherwise. It is clear that  with respect to this colouring, $\mathbb R$ can’t have a monochromatic subset of the desired cardinality. So, the statement holds in any model in which $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of countable sets, so, for example, it does not imply countable choice.

After seeing these, I think this statement can be proved without choice at all, so I wanted to ask whether there is a proof of this fact which does not use choice of any form, thank you.

Comment: It was a month ago since I asked for the exact meaning of the notation $2^{\aleph_0}\not\to(\aleph_1,\aleph_1)^2$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It means there is a colouring of the edge set of the set on the left such that there is no monochoromatic blue (or red) subset of it with cardinality shown in the first (or second) input on the right.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So in this case, we are looking for a colouring such that there is no monochromatic subset of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: It would follow by [a theorem of Galvin](https://www.dorais.org/archives/503/) that "$\aleph_1\leq2^{\aleph_0}$ + every set of reals has the Baire property + DC" implies $2^{\aleph_0}\to(\aleph_1,\aleph_1)^2$. I don't know if the assumptions are jointly consistent though.

Comment: @JasonZeshengChen These hypotheses hold in Shelah's model for all sets of reals having the Baire property without requiring an inaccessible. If there are no inaccessibles in $L,$ then DC automatically implies that $\aleph_1 \le 2^{\aleph_0}.$

Comment: @ElliotGlazer Can you provide a reference for this model?

Comment: Also, if someone can post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following theorem is due to Galvin: (see e.g., [here](https://www.dorais.org/archives/503/) )

> Let $F:[\mathbb{R}]^2\to \{0,1\}$ be a coloring such that both $F^{-1}"\{0\}, F^{-1}"\{1\}$ have the Baire property. Then there is a perfect subset that is homogeneous with respect to $F$.

So if a model satisfies $\aleph_1\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ + every set of reals has the Baire property + Galvin's theorem (which I believe uses ZF+DC), then that model will also have $2^{\aleph_0}\to(\aleph_1, \aleph_1)^2$.

In Shelah's model ($\mathcal{M}18$ in the Howard&Rubin book), every set has the BP and DC holds. Initially I wasn't sure whether $\aleph_1\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ holds in that model. But as @ElliotGlazer kindly pointed out, since Shelah's model doesn't require an inaccessible to build, we can assume that there are no inaccessibles in $L$. This will imply $\aleph_1\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ (because DC and $\aleph_1\not\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ would imply that $\aleph_1$ is inaccessible in $L$).

So Sierpinski's coloring result does not hold in Shelah's model.

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say Sierpinski's coloring does not exist in this model, since it's defined from a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @ElliotGlazer oh yeah of course, lol, didn't know what went through my head when I wrote this

Comment: Is that "theorem of Galvin" proved in ZF or in ZFC?

Comment: @bof I've been told it's proved in ZF+DC, but I've not been able to access the proof. It seems like all the given references of that paper point to an abstract in the AMS.

Comment: Apparently the only proof is in that 1981 paper by Blass which proves a more general theorem. Do you have access to that? I don't believe I do, and anyway, assuming I could follow the proof at all, I probably wouldn't be aware if it used the axiom of choice or not.

Comment: @bof from a cursory look I don't see anything stronger than DC that's used. But I would defer to the opinion of someone with more expertise than I do.

Comment: @bof Galvin's theorem is a $\Pi^2_1$ sentence. ZFC is $\Pi^2_1$-conservative over ZF + DC, so DC is sufficient.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer Is the conservativity result from Platek's Eliminating the Continuum Hypothesis?

Comment: I don't think the result is verbatim there, but if $\varphi$ is projective and $M \models ZF + DC + \exists A \subset \mathbb{R} \varphi(A),$ then you can get a model of GCH + $\exists A \varphi(A)$ by adding a Cohen subset of $\omega_1$ to $M$ and then descending to $L(R, A, G).$

Comment: @ElliotGlazer great, thanks! I asked because Platek mentioned a forcing proof of this fact due to Kripke and Silver and it made me wonder what it is. I think he was referring to something like the proof you sketched.

Comment: Actually I think this case of Galvin's theorem is choiceless, since it follows from Mycielski's result that for any meager $S \subset [\mathbb{R}]^2,$ there is perfect $P$ such that $S \cap [P]^2 = \emptyset,$ and that's $\Pi^1_3.$